# Xml with namespaces (colon) in element name in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a XML with namespaces in elements (e.g. bpmn:definitions). I need to parse it in Groovy. I tried to use XmlSlurper and XmlParser but I could not parse it properly.

The goal is print **bpmn:definitions->bpmn:definitions->@camunda:versionTag** (in xpath /bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process[1]/@camunda:versionTag).

I have the following script:

```
def xmlText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
'<bpmn:definitions exporterVersion="1.10.0" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn">' +
     '<bpmn:process camunda:versionTag="0.2" id="fund-order" isClosed="false"     isExecutable="true"></bpmn:process>
</bpmn:definitions>'

def xml = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xmlText)
println "PROPERTY: ${xml.@'bpmn:definitions'.@'bpmn:process'.@'@camunda:versionTag'}"
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names before the colons are called *"namespaces"*

Given the XML:

```
def xmlText = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions exporterVersion="1.10.0" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn">
  <bpmn:process camunda:versionTag="0.2" id="fund-order" isClosed="false" isExecutable="true"></bpmn:process>
</bpmn:definitions>'''
```

You don't need to reference the root node (that is assumed by `XmlSlurper`)

You don't need to prefix node names with `@` (that is for attributes)

The `@` should be outside the string for the last attribute

So this gives you:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xmlText)
println "PROPERTY: ${xml.'bpmn:process'.@'camunda:versionTag'}"
```

Comment: with `XmlSlurper(false, true)` you can use `xml.process` instead of `xml.'bpmn:process'`

Comment: Or just get rid of the `false, true`, and you can do `xml.process.@'camunda:versionTag'`